# Deployment of asp.net web on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am going to deploy my asp.net web on IIS 7. For this purpose I have googled and found a tutorial [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0). I followed all the steps and then run the web, in the result web is not running, its not showing its asp.net page instead of this it is showing directory listing of my web.

When I run the web through visual studio the default page in browser is http://localhost:58276/Home/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2f

Comment: Better advice would be to use the [Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/37/deploying-web-sites-on-iis/), especially since you can deploy directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: Which version of the .NET framwework does your application use? Are you targeting 2.0, 3.5, or 4.0?

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, IIs looks for a certain type of file names that it considers are entry file names.
Usually the start page for ASP.NET applications is `Default.apsx`.
(You can check that in the IIs manager -> Default Document.

Check that your start page has that name.

Comment: my application has no default.aspx page. then how can I run it.

Comment: Instructions for setting the default document in IIS 7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: When I open the web through VS 2010 the first page comes to browser
http://localhost:58276/Home/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2f

Answer (score 0):

You should check the start page as @Magnus Johansson mentioned; if that's not the problem, it might be that you're targeting the wrong ASP.NET version.

Did you specify ASP.NET 4.0 for your Application Pool? If you created your own application pool, you should open up the configuration for it and make sure it's set to .NET Framework v.4.0.

If that's not an option for your application pool, you might not have ASP.NET 4.0 set up on your system (which can happen if you install the .NET Framework 4 before you install IIS 7). If that's the case, you may need to run aspnet_regiis: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/k6h9cz8h.aspx. (The set of options you want is probably `aspnet_regiis -i`)